# Prob. 2, Sec. 14, in Fraleigh's A FIRST COURSE IN ABSTRACT ALGEBRA, 7th ed: How many elements are there in this factor group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, quotient-group

This is Prob. 2, Sec. 14, in the book *A First Course In Abstract Algebra* by John B. Fraleigh, 7th edition:

> How many elements are there in the factor group 
>   $$ \left( \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12} \right) / \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big)? $$

My Attempt:

> We note that
>   $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ has $4 \times 12 = 48$ elements, and we also note that
>   $$ \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle = \{ \ (0, 0), (2, 2), (0, 4), (2, 6), (0, 8), (2, 10)  \} $$
>   so that $\langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle$ has $6$ elements.
>
> Therefore the factor group $\left( \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12} \right) / \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big)$ has 
>   $48 / 6 = 8$ elements.
>
> More precisely, the factor group $\left( \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12} \right) / \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big)$ has the following left (or right) cosets:
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \ &= \ (0,0) + \big(  \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\  &= \  (2, 2) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\  &= \  (0, 4) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\  &= \  (2, 6) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\  &= \   (0, 8) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\  &= \  (2, 10) + \big(  \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big), 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   $$
> \begin{align} 
> \{ \ (1,0), (3, 2), (1, 4), (3, 6), (1, 8), (3, 10) \ \} \ &= \  (1, 0) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\     &= \  (1, 4) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big)  \\    &= \  (1, 8) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\     &= \  (3, 2) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\     &= \  (3, 6) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\     &= \  (3, 10) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big), 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \{ \ (0, 1 ), (2, 3), (0, 5), (2, 7), (0, 9), (2, 11) \ \} \ &= \ (0, 1) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\       &= \  (0, 5) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\       &= \  (0, 9) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\       &= \  (2, 3) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\       &= \  (2, 7) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\       &= \  (2, 11) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big),
> \end{align}
> $$
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \{ \ (1, 1), (3, 3), (1, 5), (3, 7), (1, 9), (3, 11) \ \} \ &= \ (1, 1) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\  &= \ (1, 5) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (1, 9) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (3, 3) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (3, 7) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (3, 11) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle \big),
> \end{align}
> $$
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \{ \ (0, 2), (2, 4), (0, 6), (2, 8), (0, 10), (2, 0) \ \} \ &= \
>  (0, 2) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (0, 6) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \ (0, 10) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (2, 0) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\  &= \ (2, 4) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (2, 8) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big), 
> \end{align}
> $$ 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \{ \ (0, 3), (2, 5), (0, 7), (2, 9), (0, 11), (2, 1) \ \} \  &= \ 
>  (0, 3) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (0, 7) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (0, 11) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (2, 1) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (2, 5) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= \  (2, 9) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big), 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \{ \ (1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 6), (3, 8), (1, 10), (3, 0) \ \} \  &= \ (1, 2) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= (1, 6) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= (1, 10) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= (3, 0) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= (3, 4) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &=  (3, 8) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big), 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   and 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \{ \ (1, 3), (3, 5), (1, 7), (3, 9), (1, 11), (3, 1) \ \} \  &= \ (1, 3) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= (1, 7) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= (1, 11) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= (3, 1) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &= (3, 5) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big) \\ &=  (3, 9) + \big( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle \big)
> \end{align}. 
> $$

Is my answer correct? Is my calculation correct in each and every detail? Is my logic correct?

If not, then where are the problems in my attempt?

Comment: You've got the wrong subgroup. You only listed the elements of $\langle(2,2)\rangle$. At least I would read $\langle 2\rangle\times\langle 2\rangle$ to be the same as $\langle(2,0)\rangle+\langle(0,2)\rangle$. And therefore that subgroup would have all the elements of the form $(2m,2n), 0\le m<2, 0\le n<6$. But may be Fraleigh has different conventioins

Comment: I mean that for example, because $8\in\langle 2\rangle\le\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ and $2\in\langle 2\rangle\le\Bbb{Z}_4$, we must then have $(2,8)\in\langle2\rangle\times\langle 2\rangle$. Consequently the $\langle 2\rangle\times \langle 2\rangle$ has 12 elements, and the quotient group only four.

Comment: Hi Saaqib: what you've done here is used a question-and-answer site as a grading site. That is not something we encourage. However, that does not mean you can't ask your question. Why don't you put your question as a question and your answer as an answer?  I mean... that's the _whole point_.  I'm sure any problems in your proposed solution will be caught (perhaps they are even more likely to be caught) if you post as a solution.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes. But we also require that they show us what they have tried.

Comment: @stevengregory .... a self-answered question does that.  Nobody says context _has_ to be in the question body, but it often should be.

Comment: @rschwieb I was not as clear as I thought I was. I was trying to point out that he showed us what he had tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12}| = 48 $$
$$|\langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle| = 2 \cdot 6 = 12$$
$$|\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12} / \langle 2 \rangle \times  \langle 2 \rangle| = 4$$

$$(0,0) +\langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle = \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
   (0,0) & (0,2) & (0,4) & (0,6) & (0,8) & (0,10)\\
   (2,0) & (2,2) & (2,4) & (2,6) & (2,8) & (2,10)\\
\end{array}\right\}$$

$$(1,0) +\langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle = \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
   (1,0) & (1,2) & (1,4) & (1,6) & (1,8) & (1,10)\\
   (3,0) & (3,2) & (3,4) & (3,6) & (3,8) & (3,10)\\
\end{array}\right\}$$

$$(0,1) +\langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle = \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
   (0,1) & (0,3) & (0,5) & (0,7) & (0,9) & (0,11)\\
   (2,1) & (2,3) & (2,5) & (2,7) & (2,9) & (2,11)\\
\end{array}\right\}$$

$$(1,1) +\langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle = \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
   (1,1) & (1,3) & (1,5) & (1,7) & (1,9) & (1,11)\\
   (3,1) & (3,3) & (3,5) & (3,7) & (3,9) & (3,11)\\
\end{array}\right\}$$